# Magento Login page

Tags: magento

If I want to make Last Name to be not Mandatory in Magento Registration page
how could I do that ?

please help or point me in right direction so that I don't mess with rest of the system working.

That's what I did

```
I went to the template file Customer/widget/name.phtml 
then in div class field name-lastname  i remove the class="required"
```

Please confirm it wont mess with any other parts of Magento

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is right. It wont affect others.

The file that does the validation is /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
  if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last name can\'t be empty');
    }
```

Please override this.

You may also please go to the `eav_attribute` table and you can find `lastname` (id -7) column. Please set the `is_required` to 0.